# The probability of getting a 7

Tags: probability

This problem is probably too easy for all you math geniuses out there, but I am having trouble understanding it, so here it is:

> An athlete has 10 cards, numbered 1 to 10. Every day, he picks a card randomly and does that number of pushups. He doesn't replace the card, and picks until all the cards are gone. If after a certain number of tries, the athlete has done a total of 12 pushups, then the probability of him/her picking a 7 as the very next card is $\frac{a}{b}$. What is a + b?

I know that I have to count the possibilities of getting a 12:

- **2 cards**

The possibilities would be 2 and 10, 3 and 9, 4 and 8, 5 and 7, which would make **4 possibilities**.

- **3 cards**

1, 2, 9 | 1, 3, 8 | 1, 4, 7 | 1, 5, 6 | 2, 3, 7 | 2, 4, 6 | 3, 4, 5 | which would be **7 possibilities**.

- **4 cards**

1, 2, 3, 6 | 1, 2, 4, 5 | which is **2 possibilities**.

There cannot be more than 4 cards: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 would make 15.

The total number of possibilities for getting a 12 is **17**, and out of those, there are 3 of them that will pick the card 7, which means 14 out of the 17 possibilities will be valid for the problem.

I don't know how to continue from here. Should I solve for the probability each of the three cases listed above separately, then add them, or is there a better method?

Comment: What trouble are you having understanding it, exactly?

Comment: You need to sort out the various ways the man might have done a total of $12$ pushups.  For example, he might have drawn the $2$ and then the $10$.  Or maybe he drew $4$ then $1$ then $7$. And so on.  Handle each case separately (well, the order of the draws doesn't matter, just the number of values drawn and whether or not $7$ has appeared already).

Comment: What particular part of the problem are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @lulu So sorry, I will post what I have done.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have posted my current understanding of how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Max0815 I have posted my current understanding of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\overline{
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
$$

- The number of decks for which the first $2$ cards sum to $12$ is $(4)(2!)(8!)$, where

  - The factor $4$ counts the ordered pairs $(2,10),\;(3,9),\;(4,8),\;(5,7)$.

    The factor $2!$ allows each pair to be permuted.

    The factor $8!$ counts the permutations of the remaining cards.

  The number of decks for which the first $2$ cards sum to $12$ and the next card is $7$ is $(3)(2!)(7!)$, where

  - The factor $3$ counts the ordered pairs $(2,10),\;(3,9),\;(4,8)$.

    The factor $2!$ allows each pair to be permuted.

    The factor $7!$ counts the permutations of the cards remaining after the $7$.

$$
\overline{
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
$$

- The number of decks for which the first $3$ cards sum to $12$ is
  is $(7)(3!)(7!)$, where

  - The factor $7$ counts the ordered triples $(1,2,9),\;(1,3,8),\;(1,4,7)\;(1,5,6),\;(2,3,7),\;(2,4,6),\;(3,4,5)$.

    The factor $3!$ allows each triple to be permuted.

    The factor $7!$ counts the permutations of the remaining cards.

  The number of decks for which the first $3$ cards sum to $12$  and the next card is $7$ is $(5)(3!)(6!)$, where

  - The factor $5$ counts the ordered triples $(1,2,9),\;(1,3,8),\;(1,5,6),\;(2,4,6),\;(3,4,5)$.

    The factor $3!$ allows each triple to be permuted.

    The factor $6!$ counts the permutations of the cards remaining after the $7$.

$$
\overline{
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
$$

- The number of decks for which the first $4$ cards sum to $12$ is
  is $(2)(4!)(6!)$, where

  - The factor $2$ counts the ordered quadruples $(1,2,3,6),\;(1,2,4,5)$.

    The factor $4!$ allows each quadruple to be permuted.

    The factor $6!$ counts the permutations of the remaining cards.

  The number of decks for which the first $4$ cards sum to $12$ and the next card is $7$ is $(2)(4!)(5!)$, where

  - The factor $2$ counts the ordered quadruples $(1,2,3,6),\;(1,2,4,5)$.

    The factor $4!$ allows each quadruple to be permuted.

    The factor $5!$ counts the permutations of the cards remaining after the $7$.

$$
\overline{
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}
$$
Hence, the probability that the next card is $7$, given that the previous cards sum to $12$ is
$$
\frac
{\;\,(3)(2!)(7!)+(5)(3!)(6!)+(2)(4!)(5!)}
{\;\,(4)(2!)(8!)+(7)(3!)(7!)+(2)(4!)(6!)}
=
\frac{8}{79}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the relative probabilities of getting a $2, 3$ or $4$ card sum of $12$.

These are:$$\frac{4}{\binom{10}{2}};\frac{7}{\binom{10}{3}}; \frac{2}{\binom{10}{4}} = \frac{4}{45}; \frac{7}{120}; \frac{2}{210} = \frac{448}{5040}; \frac{294}{5040}; \frac{48}{5040}$$

Given the sum is $12$, the actual probabilities of being a $2, 3$ card or $4$ card sum are:

$$\frac{448}{790}; \frac{294}{790}; \frac{48}{790}$$

The sum of all $3$ probabilities of drawing a $7$ from each of the $3$ card quantities is therefore:

$$P(7) = \frac{448}{790}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{8} + \frac{294}{790}\cdot \frac{5}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{7} + \frac{48}{790}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = 0.101266$$